# Jquery input.files equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I have a simple html form with a single file upload input. ([jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/5zJLp/)

In the past, I have accessed the file selected by the user using `input.files`, however I am at a loss as to how to do this with JQuery;

Code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#cmdSubmit").bind("click", function () {
        var file = document.getElementById("fileInput").files[0];
        alert(file); //A

        file = $("#fileInput").val();
        alert(file); //B

        file = $("#fileInput").files[0];
        alert(file); //C

    });        
});​
```

Option **A** give me what I expect, a file object. However, option **B** simply gives me the name of the uploaded file, and (as far as I can tell) not the file itself.

Option **C** shows that `files` is undefined.

What is the Jquery equivalent of `input.files`?

Note: I have no objection to using native javascript; but given that I am using JQuery throughout the rest of this project I'd prefer to use it here as well if possible.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You have to access the element. Try:

```
file = $("#fileInput")[0].files[0];
alert(file); //C
```

or (thank you Jack)

```
file = $("#fileInput").prop('files')[0];
alert(file);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QmSh8/)

Comment: `.prop('files')[0]` is more likely to work than `.attr('file')`

Answer (score 4):

Try the below code

```
var file = $("#fileInput").get(0).files[0];
 alert(file);
```

Thanks

Comment: This looks correct as per: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/

The FAQ just mentions that this is slower...

Why the downvote?

Answer (score 3):

jQuery doesn't provide a wrapper for the Files API. So there isn't a jQuery style way to do this, at least not built into the jQuery core.

Your options:

- stick with option A
- wait for jQuery to include such a wrapper (they might not)
- find an extension written by someone else (if one exists)
- write an extension yourself

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $("#cmdSubmit").bind("click", function () {
       alert(this.files);
     });        
});​
```