# Get File from Input field in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have this code on my page then it works

index.html

```
<input type="file" name="data[Post][picture]"  hidden="1" onchange="uploadPhoto(this.files)" id="PostPicture"/>
```

script.js

```
function uploadPhoto(files){

    //TODO

    console.log(files);
}
```

but that code requires me to put `uploadPhoto()` function out of jquery `$()` function. I have certain problems with variable scope and so I don't want to get my function outside of `document.ready` function.

for that I did something like this

```
$(function(){
    var uploadPhoto = function(){


        //TODO

        console.log($('#PostPicture').files);
    };

    $('#PostPicture').on('change',uploadPhoto);
});
```

and it logs `undefined` in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery results set does not have a `files` attribute, you need to access the element directly:

```
var files = $("#fileInput")[0].files;
```

or

```
var files = $("#fileInput").prop('files');
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13747921/441907