# send file using ajax with other type of input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i already had a form which uses ajax to save the the data to the database. so i have this sample

Html code

```
<input id="product_name" type="text" >
<input id="product_description"/>
<input id="product_img" type="file" accept="image/*"/>
<button id="btnSave">Save</button>
```

Javascrip Code

```
$("#btnSave").click(function(){
    p_name = $("#product_name").val();
    p_des = $("#product_description").val();
    p_image = $("#product_img").prop('files')[0];
    data = {
       'product_name':p_name,
       'product_description':p_des
    }

   $.post('url_here',data,function(response){
       console.log(response);
   });
});
```

i do have this info [Jquery input.files equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747892/jquery-input-files-equivalent?answertab=active#tab-top) but i cant make it passed as a $_FILE for php.Please give me some example codes combining the input type text and file without using the form tag and using jquery ajax.

Comment: If you can't/won't use the `<form>` **tag**, use the `form` **property**.

Comment: im afraid to do it since i already had many codes for the system im making that doesn't use form tag.i cant afford to redo all my codes before

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Comment: Why 'using jquery ajax'? Firstly, you should explain that as soon as you've asked the question. And secondly, if your question changed, open a new question, or, at least, put it as 'UPDATE: I need to use jquery ajax'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData):

```
document.getElementById('btnSave').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('product_name', document.getElementById('product_name').value);
  fd.append('product_description', document.getElementById('product_description').value);
  fd.append('product_name', document.getElementById('product_img').files[0]);

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', 'url_here');

  xhr.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
  });

  xhr.send(fd);
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

Since you want to use jQuery AJAX (I have no idea why, since it was not prepared to use XHR2), you can workaround by telling it to not process the `data` parameter, e.g:

```
$('#btnSave').click(function() {
  p_name = $('#product_name').val();
  p_des = $('#product_description').val();
  p_image = $('#product_img').prop('files')[0];

  var data = new FormData();
  data.append('product_name', p_name);
  data.append('product_description', p_des);
  data.appned('product_img', p_image);


  $.ajax({
    url: 'url_here',
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response){
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: oh im sorry .. but i need to use jquery ajax..but you gave me the great idea i needed so plus 1 for you :D thank man..

Comment: @jameshwartlopez I updated my answer showing how to use it.