# uncaught TypeError cannot read property '0'

Tags: javascript

I am trying to upload a file using javascript and asp.net mvc 5. But I am getting this error.

> uncaught typeError cannot read property '0'

Here is my codes :

```
$("#btnReciveDocument").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    debugger;
    var formdata = new FormData(); //FormData object
    var fileInput = $("#fileInput")

    //uncaught typeerror cannot read property '0'
    formdata.append(fileInput.files[0].name, fileInput.files[0]);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/Home/Upload');
    xhr.send(formdata);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `fileInput.files` returns `undefined`. You probably need `var fileInput = $("#fileInput")[0]` to get the HTML element, because otherwise you're handling a jQuery element.

Comment: Check what do you have inside `fileInput` because this means that you have empty array and you are trying to use first element of that array with `fileInput.files[0].name`

Comment: @vaske an empty array wouldn't throw an error that says there is no property `0`, it would have complained about `name`. Moreover, jQuery objects do not have a `files` property, this is part of HTMLInputElement interface. [You need to extract the HTMLElement from the jQuery wrapper or use the jQuery wrapper interface to get the `files` content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747892/jquery-input-files-equivalent)

Comment: yeah you are right.

Comment: @VLAZ i have tried this method and its working fine thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is due to the fact that you are trying to access the property `files` of `$("#fileInput")`: equivalent to `$("#fileInput").files`, that has `undefined` as results.

Without more knowledge of your DOM i cannot provide you a solution.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion i have tried with method '$("#fileInput")[0]'  Which is perfect